# R: Send email to Outlook with utf-8 subject

Tags: r, utf-8

I'm using package 'RDCOMClient' to send email to Outlook

And Here'the code

```
sendEmail =  function(To=To, Subject=Subject, msgBody=msgBody,file="") {

      OutApp=COMCreate("Outlook.Application")

      OutMail=OutApp$CreateItem(0)

      OutMail[["To"]]=To

      OutMail[["Subject"]]=Subject

      OutMail[["Body"]]=msgBody

      if(file!="") OutMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(file)

     OutMail$Send()

    }
```

It can send email, but I can't set the Subject in Chinese.

`OutMail[["Subject"]]<-Subject`

Do anyone knows how to let OutMail[["Subject"]] to recognize the subject in utf-8?